# Showing that $f(z)$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $x\in \Bbb R^n, y\in\Bbb R$, and $z\in\Bbb C$. For a fixed $\lambda\in\Bbb R^n$ and a smooth, compactly supported function $\varphi\in\mathcal D(\Bbb R^{n+1})$, I want to show that
$$
f(z):=\int_{\Bbb R^n} e^{-i\lambda\cdot x} \left( \int_{\Bbb R} e^{-izy} \varphi(x,y) dy \right) dx
$$
is an analytic function.

The hint says that using Fubini's theorem and Morera's theorem is the way to go. My knowledge of complex analysis is very rusty so I'd really appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: Do you remember what Morera's theorem says?

Comment: If the integral along any closed loop is zero, then the function is analytic?

Comment: Yes. The better version is that a function $f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$, where $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open, is holomorphic _if and only if_ $$\int_{\partial \Delta} f(z)\,dz = 0$$ for every closed triangle $\Delta \subset U$. But the other version works here too. So you want to compute $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz$ for a closed loop $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Can you then see how Fubini could be used?

Comment: Ah, I think I see kind of see it now. Since $\varphi$ has compact support, the innermost integral doesn't really extend to infinity.

Comment: Even if it did, that wouldn't pose a problem if $\varphi$ decays fast enough. But the compact support and boundedness of $\varphi$ make the justification of applying Fubini's theorem easier.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes forget it. $f(z) = \hat{\varphi}(\lambda,z)$ where $\hat{\varphi}(\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} e^{-i \omega. x} \varphi(x)dx$ is the Fourier transform of $\varphi$. Since $\varphi$ is compactly supported and $L^1$ we can extend its Fourier transform to $\omega \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, and of course it is analytic.

Comment: @user1952009 That's really interesting. May I ask how do you show that the extension to $\omega \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ makes it analytic?

Comment: Because $G(z) = \int_a^b g(t) e^{-izt}dt$ is analytic whenever $g \in L^1([a,b])$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Morera's theorem, we need to verify

$$\int_{\partial\Delta} f(z)\,dz = 0\tag{1}$$

for all triangles $\Delta \subset \mathbb{C}$. Using the definition of $f$ and Fubini's theorem, we have

$$\int_{\partial\Delta} f(z)\,dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{- i \lambda\cdot x} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x,y) \int_{\partial \Delta} e^{-izy}\,dz\,dy\,dx.$$

Since for every fixed $y$ the function $z \mapsto e^{-izy}$ is holomorphic, the innermost integral vanishes for all $y$, and thus $(1)$ follows.

The application of Fubini's theorem is justified because $(x,y,z) \mapsto e^{-i\lambda x} e^{-izy}\varphi(x,y)$ is continuous, hence measurable, and the integral of the modulus is finite.